# How to open a popup, MVC webgrid, dynamic columns

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a webgrid, which is stated below

```
@grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webgrid", 
              headerStyle: "webgrid-header", 
              footerStyle: "webgrid-footer", 
              alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row", 
              selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-selected-row", 
              rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style"
             )
```

Since my columns are dynamic i am not defining any columns in the webgrid.

My question is, How do I link a particular column to open a popup?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a class to the item (an achor tag? ) where you want to show a popup when clicking on that. So your HTML may be rendered as something like

```
<a href="user/details/12" class="aPopup">View details</a>
```

Now have a little bit of jQuery code to listen to the click event of the link and show a popup. You may simply call the [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/window.open) method which opens a page in a new window or use plugin to show a model popup.

```
$(function(){
  $("a.aPopup").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();

     var popupUrl=$(this).attr("href");

     //code to show popup here
     //window.open or model popup plugin call

  });    
});
```

There are a number of plugins there to show a model popup. check out [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/).

Comment: Hi Shyju, when i gave href its not rendering the same as html instead it shows <a href="user/details/12" class="aPopup">View Extra details</a>. How can i make this look like HTML with hyperlink. I am doing this from my sql query.

Comment: what you mean by html with hyperlink ? Is that `a` tag not enough for you ?

Comment: so my sql has SELECT DISTINCT
  r.ReportName AS [Report Name]
 ,r.ReportDesc AS [Report Desc] 
 ,'<a href="user/details/12" class="aPopup">View Extra details</a>' AS [Report Extra Details]
FROM r.Reports now when i run this on web grid i was expecting the display as Voew Extra Details with out the <a href and all. Why on the webgrid it shows as <a href="user/details/12" class="aPopup">View Extra details</a> ?

Comment: Hi Shyju, basically i want to render the column data "<a href="user/details/12" class="aPopup">View Extra details</a>" as html on the grid, rest your jquery should work for me.

Comment: I solved the issue foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> keyValuePair in eachFlowRow)
        {
            if (keyValuePair.Key.Contains("Report Extra Details"))
            {
                var newEntry = new KeyValuePair<string, object>(keyValuePair.Key, @Html.Raw("<a href='Home/Index' class='aPopup'>Vijay</a>"));
                row.Add(newEntry);
            }
            else
            {
                row.Add(keyValuePair);
            }
        }